# Multiply two 2D matrices in LpConstraint

Tags: python, pulp

I'm trying to do a cutting and stock optimization problem.
But in restricao1 I'm not able to do x_variaveis * padroes, because they are two 4x11 matrices and apparently p.lpSum or p.LpConstraint can not do that.

```py
import pulp as p
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

m = 4 
n = 11
L = 70
b = np.array([30, 30, 30, 120])
l = np.array([20, 22, 25, 26])
padroes = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3], 
                   [0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0],
                   [2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
set_J = range(0, m)
set_I = range(0, n)

x_variaveis = {(i,j) :p.LpVariable(cat=p.LpInteger, lowBound=0, name="x_{0}_{1}".format(i,j)) for i in set_I for j in set_J}

y_variaveis = {i :p.LpVariable(cat=p.LpBinary, name="y_{0}".format(i)) for i in set_I}

restricao1 = {j : p.LpConstraint(e=p.lpSum(x_variaveis[i,j] * padroes[i,j] for i in set_I), sense=p.LpConstraintGE, rhs=b[j], name="restricao_{0}".format(j)) for j in set_J}

restricao2 = {i : p.LpConstraint(e=p.lpSum(l[j] * x_variaveis[i,j] for j in set_J), sense=p.LpConstraintLE,rhs=L * y_variaveis[i], name="restricao_{0}".format(i)) for i in set_I}

fun_obj = p.lpSum(y_variaveis[i] for i in set_I)
```

I need this type of multiplication:

```py
a=[[1, 5],
  [4, 0]]
b=[[6, 2],
  [3, 1]]

print(a*b)
out:[[6, 10],
     [12, 0]]
```

How I do this multiplication?

Comment: _I get the following error_ - what is it?

Comment: `set_I` cannot be used to index `padroes` in its current shape. This is probably a transposition error in `i,j`. This has nothing to do with matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Reinderien sorry, it's my first question and the photo didn't load

Comment: @Reinderien I switched to padroes[j,i] and it worked. Thank you!